# Complex Integral With 3 singularities

Tags: integration

$$ \int_{|z+1|=5} \frac{e^z}{(z-2)(z+4)^2} \, dz $$

So all the singularities are within the contour so I am not sure of what way to proceed. Do I just evaluate at every singularity? We have not been over the Residue Theorem so I do not know where to go from here.

Comment: I have no idea what $C(-1;5)$ means.

Comment: Its the area of integration thats a Circle placed at x=-1 with radius 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use partial fractions on the denominator, which gives
$$ \frac{1}{(z-2)(z+4)^2} = \frac{1}{36}\frac{1}{z-2} - \frac{1}{36} \frac{1}{z+4} - \frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{(z+4)^2}, $$
and now you can use the Cauchy integral formula on each term with no difficulty.

(Alternatively, you can use the CIF with $ f(z) = e^{z}/(z-2)$ and $"(z-w)^{n+1}"=(z+4)^2$, and then separately on $f(z)/(z+4)^2$. However, it's less obvious that you can just add these up. [Although recall you can deform the contour into two small circles, one about each singularity.])